# Mongoid Embed documents send 2 query on delete Bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

```
class parent
  fields :count
  embed_many :children
end

class children
  embed_in: :parent
end
```

Console

```
obj = Parent.first
obj.count #=> 2
obj.childrens #=> [children, children]
#here-to-update
obj.count = 5
obj.childrens.delete( obj.childrens.last )
#mongo-query
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=db collection=parents selector={"_id"=>"52b277c62aa194882f000007"} update={"$pull"=>{"childrens"=>{"_id"=>3}}} flags=[]

obj.reload
obj.count #=> 2 (does not update, Bug)
obj.childrens #=> [children]
```

In relational database, this is not a bug becuz u need to update 2 tables. But in mongo and since it is embed document. I think it's a waste to send 2 queries to update it.

Any solution?

Comment: `obj.count` sould be `obj.children.count`?

Comment: `obj.count` should raise `NoMethodError: undefined method count for #<Parent:0x00000004e21bb8>`

Comment: As u can see, i have filed :count on Parent. so there is a Parent#count. and its signature is equal to children.length

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a 's' to name your embed relation.

```
class Order
  field :count, type: Integer
  embeds_many :Products
end

class Product
  embedded_in :Order
end
```

Plus, save your changes.

```
Order.set(:count, 5)
```

Do you know that you can either do ?

```
order = Order.first
order.product_ids.count
```

Then you don't need a field into your Order model.

EDIT:
- Well, to change the `count` field value, you have to update your model and then to save it.
- When deleting the embedded relation, it removes the embedded object.
You can't make these two operations by only one.
Hope I answered.

Comment: yes, your answer is pretty much what i have expected from my code above. But still, mongoid didn't use the benefit of embedded document. I hope they will provide it soon.